# Using Lucene in java to calculate MAP

Tags: java, information-retrieval, lucene, information-extraction

I am new to lucene (using lucene jar with a java university project) and I wanted to know,

Does lucene supply out of the box mean average precision? 

Assuming it does the indexing and do supply some other functionalities (which are sadly 
poorley documented...).

Any help will be appreciated.


**Just to be clear - 

It is for a university project BUT I am allowed to use ANY functionality lucene 
supplys...**

Comment: You do have [`org.apache.lucene.benchmark.quality.QualityStats.getAvp()`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_0_3/api/contrib-benchmark/org/apache/lucene/benchmark/quality/QualityStats.html#getAvp()) to get average precision. Getting to MAP from there shouldn't be that hard I guess...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do have [`org.apache.lucene.benchmark.quality.QualityStats.getAvp()`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_0_3/api/contrib-benchmark/org/apache/lucene/benchmark/quality/QualityStats.html#getAvp%28%29) to get average precision.

This returns the Average precision for a single query when running a quality benchmark.

Getting the mean from the set of query should be fairly easy from this point.